# Facing error while using Google's places API in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I have implemented Google's places API in my iOS App but facing this error randomly.

> "Autocomplete error The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)."

Here is my Code:

```
GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment;

_placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];

[_placesClient autocompleteQuery:@"elante"
                          bounds:nil
                          filter:filter
                        callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                            if (error != nil) {
                                NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);

                                [self getPlaces];
                                return;
                            }

                            for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                                NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                            }
                        }];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864256/facing-error-while-using-googles-places-api-in-ios-app Seems to be a recent bug

Comment: Any fix for this? Or anywhere mentioned by Google?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188842%2B%20status:open%20type:bug%20&terms= Apparently there are looking for it.